# How to get variables for calculating "intrinsic value" of Berkshire Hathaway?

Tags: balance-sheet, net-worth, annual-report

I would like to calculate Berkshire Hathaway's balance sheet value and "intrinsic value" as described in [Warren Buffett's Berkshire Hathaway - Uncovering Intrinsic Value](http://www.gillenmarkets.com/featured_articles/warren-buffett-s-berkshire-hathaway---uncovering-the-intrinsic-value.cfm). However, I can't figure out how the author got some of his numbers.

What are the proper values for these variables, and how do you find them? (or calculate them?)

Berkshire Hathaway's:

- Other Liabilities
- Total Float
- Number of shares to divide by (for class BRK-B)